# Android app testing using selenium

Tags: java, android, cucumber, selenium-ide, gherkin

Scenario: Output of the first apk file is the input for the second APK file.

How Can i able to test this in single test using selenium?

Already tried with Before steps, but nothing helps

Comment: Not sure this is applicable to the IDE. Also: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Please flush out this question.